# How to create multiple arrays with same elements from single array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I am working on one form where user can upload file with data with below headers.

```
0-300 | 300-500| 500-1000| 1000-5000|>5000
2.5   | 2.5    | 2.5     | 2.4      | 2.4
1.2   | 1.2    | 1.2     | 1.3      | 1.4
-------------------------------------------
```

Now i have insert this data in db in one column as a json data.
so, for first row data will generate like :

```
[{'lb' : '0'; 'ub': '1000';'value': '2.5'},
 {'lb': '1000';'ub': 'INF'; 'value' : '2.4'}]
```

and for second row :

```
[ {'lb' : '0'; 'ub': '1000';'value': '1.2'},
  {'lb': '1000';'ub': '5000'; 'value' : '1.3'},
  {'lb': 'INF';'ub': 'INF'; 'value' : '1.4'}].
```

In above example i have to compare current value with next value and  if both are same then there will create one object if i got different then i have to create second object and so on.
lb means i have to take lower band of first node and ub means upper band.

I am using foreach with current and next operator of php but stuck to create proper objects.

```
$slabs = //each row from excel.
foreach($slabs as $key => $value) {
        $b = $value;
        $c = next($slabs) ?? false;
        
        if($b == $c) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r('YES'); stuck here//
            echo '</pre>';
        }else{
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r('NO');
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Please help me to create logic on this scenario.

```
$slabs = Array ( 
    [0-300] => 2.5 
    [300-500] => 2.5 
    [500-1000] => 2.5 
    [1000-5000] => 2.5 
    [>5000] => 2.5 
    );
```

Comment: It would be useful if you showed some more of you logic for reading the (i assume) csv file so we knew what was going to be in `$slabs`

Comment: you could probably consolidate all of the data into one array then print, or have it written while you're creating the table, your json string is malformed though so you better check that one out first

Comment: In $slabs = Array
(
    [0-300] => 2.5
    [300-500] => 2.5
    [500-1000] => 2.5
    [1000-5000] => 2.5
    [>5000] => 2.5
)  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ah good job I asked, that is not how you defined the data initially

Comment: ok @RiggsFolly. can you help me to create it in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through your slabs array, outputting a new object every time you see a different value. I've implemented this through two functions; the first (`key_values`) splits the key into upper and lower bounds, and the second (`convert_slabs`) loops over the `$slabs` array and splits it into contiguous regions by value.

```php
function key_values($key) {
    if ($key[0] == '>') {
        [$lower, $upper] = [substr($key, 1), 'INF'];
    }
    else {
        [$lower, $upper] = explode('-', $key);
    }
    return [$lower, $upper];
}

function convert_slabs($slabs) {
    $bounds = array();
    $last_value = reset($slabs);
    [$lb, $ub] = [$lower, $upper] = key_values(key($slabs));
    while ($value = next($slabs)) {
        [$lower, $upper] = key_values(key($slabs));
        // new entry required?
        if ($value != $last_value) {
            $bounds[] = (object)['lb' => $lb, 'ub' => $ub, 'value' => $last_value];
            [$lb, $ub] = [$lower, $upper];
            $last_value = $value;
        }
        else {
            // no, just extend the upper bound
            $ub = $upper;
        }
    }
    // add the last object
    $bounds[] = (object)['lb' => $lb, 'ub' => $ub, 'value' => $last_value];
    return $bounds;
}
```

Test code (`str_replace` on JSON conversion is just to make output more readable):

```php
$slabs_array = array(
    [ '0-300' => 2.5, '300-500' => 2.5, '500-1000' => 2.5, '1000-5000' => 2.4, '>5000' => 2.4 ],
    [ '0-300' => 1.2, '300-500' => 1.2, '500-1000' => 1.2, '1000-5000' => 1.3, '>5000' => 1.4 ],
    [ '0-300' => 2.5, '300-500' => 2.5, '500-1000' => 2.5, '1000-5000' => 2.5, '>5000' => 2.5 ],
    [ '0-300' => 4.5, '300-500' => 2.5, '500-1000' => 2.5, '1000-5000' => 2.5, '>5000' => 3.5 ],
    [ '0-300' => 4.5, '300-500' => 3.5, '500-1000' => 3.5, '1000-5000' => 3.5, '>5000' => 3.5 ],
    [ '0-300' => 1.5, '300-500' => 2.5, '500-1000' => 2.5, '1000-5000' => 2.5, '>5000' => 1.5 ],
    [ '0-300' => 1.5, '300-500' => 2.5, '500-1000' => 3.5, '1000-5000' => 2.5, '>5000' => 3.5 ],
    [ '0-300' => 1.5, '300-500' => 2.5, '500-1000' => 2.5, '1000-5000' => 1.5, '>5000' => 1.5 ]
);

foreach ($slabs_array as $slabs) {
    $result = convert_slabs($slabs);
    echo str_replace('},{', "},\n{", json_encode($result)) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
[{"lb":"0","ub":"1000","value":2.5},
{"lb":"1000","ub":"INF","value":2.4}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"1000","value":1.2},
{"lb":"1000","ub":"5000","value":1.3},
{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":1.4}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"INF","value":2.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":4.5},
{"lb":"300","ub":"5000","value":2.5},
{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":3.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":4.5},
{"lb":"300","ub":"INF","value":3.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":1.5},
{"lb":"300","ub":"5000","value":2.5},
{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":1.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":1.5},
{"lb":"300","ub":"500","value":2.5},
{"lb":"500","ub":"1000","value":3.5},
{"lb":"1000","ub":"5000","value":2.5},
{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":3.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":1.5},
{"lb":"300","ub":"1000","value":2.5},
{"lb":"1000","ub":"INF","value":1.5}]
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/L2ZEM)

Comment: @mickmackusa `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` spreads the objects out one key per line which makes it hard to see what is going on. https://3v4l.org/KgeNr

Answer (score 1):

I've used @Nick's sample data since it has great test data and declared it as `$array` in my sandbox demo.

The first squirrelly bit is the parsing of your ranged expressions because they are inconsistently formatted.  My snippet will trim the optional `>` from the start of the string, and append `-INF` to the end of the string, then parse that new string and only isolate the first two values delimited by a hyphen.

Next, it is just a matter of tracking the value changes between each iteration.  When a new value is encountered, push the current range, then start a new range.  When finished iterating, push one more entry so that the last entry is not omitted from the collection.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/B1TWX))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $merged = [];
    $entry = ['lb' => null, 'ub' => null, 'value' => null];
    foreach ($row as $range => $value) {
        sscanf(ltrim("$range-INF", '>'), '%[^-]-%[^-]', $lowerBound, $upperBound);
        if ($value !== $entry['value']) {
            if ($entry['lb'] !== null) {
                $merged[] = $entry;
            }
            $entry = ['lb' => $lowerBound, 'ub' => $upperBound, 'value' => $value];
        } else {
            $entry['ub'] = $upperBound;
        }
    }
    $merged[] = $entry;
    echo json_encode($merged) . "\n\n";
}
```

Output: (same data as @Nick's)

```
[{"lb":"0","ub":"1000","value":2.5},{"lb":"1000","ub":"INF","value":2.4}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"1000","value":1.2},{"lb":"1000","ub":"5000","value":1.3},{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":1.4}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"INF","value":2.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":4.5},{"lb":"300","ub":"5000","value":2.5},{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":3.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":4.5},{"lb":"300","ub":"INF","value":3.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":1.5},{"lb":"300","ub":"5000","value":2.5},{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":1.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":1.5},{"lb":"300","ub":"500","value":2.5},{"lb":"500","ub":"1000","value":3.5},{"lb":"1000","ub":"5000","value":2.5},{"lb":"5000","ub":"INF","value":3.5}]

[{"lb":"0","ub":"300","value":1.5},{"lb":"300","ub":"1000","value":2.5},{"lb":"1000","ub":"INF","value":1.5}]
```